# Fast switching between REST servers in android

Tags: android

I'm developing simple REST client for Android, and make in local network REST server for development purposes. How I cat easy switch between local development REST server and remote production REST server? (for example `http://192.168.0.3:4567/orders`, `http://192.168.0.3:4567/orders/:id` -> `http://someremoteserver.com/orders`, `http://someremoteserver.com/orders/id:`).

PS: I'm using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) REST library.

Comment: put url as string in string.xml `<string name="url">your url</string>` get this string when you have to call server `getString(R.string.url)` . If you want to change it then you have to only change in string.xml only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working extensively on different development environments, you should learn about Android Studio's support for build variants. It enables you to quickly switch from one environment to another.

http://blog.brainattica.com/how-to-work-with-flavours-on-android/

Comment: Thanks, I add productFlavors, and set `HOST` variable via `gradle.properties`